# How to work with celldblclick event in extjs 5

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I have a requirement, in a grid panel we have 3 columns. "Name", "Age" and "Height".

So if an User will doubleclick on any cell under "Name" column then it will redirect to a new window.

`

```
{
  xtype : 'gridpanel',
  region: 'center',
  height : 400,                
  title : 'Search Results',
  id : 'searchResultsGrid',`
```

I know we have to use "`celldblclick` event, but not sure how to use it. I am using extjs version 5

This is the reference for celldblclick in extjs 5 document.
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.panel.Table-event-celldblclick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like that

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
            fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
            data: {
                'items': [{
                    'name': 'Lisa',
                    "email": "lisa@simpsons.com",
                    "phone": "555-111-1224"
                }, {
                    'name': 'Bart',
                    "email": "bart@simpsons.com",
                    "phone": "555-222-1234"
                }, {
                    'name': 'Homer',
                    "email": "homer@simpsons.com",
                    "phone": "555-222-1244"
                }, {
                    'name': 'Marge',
                    "email": "marge@simpsons.com",
                    "phone": "555-222-1254"
                }]
            },
            proxy: {
                type: 'memory',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'items'
                }
            }
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            title: 'Simpsons',
            store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
            columns: [{
                text: 'Name',
                dataIndex: 'name'
            }, {
                text: 'Email',
                dataIndex: 'email',
                flex: 1
            }, {
                text: 'Phone',
                dataIndex: 'phone'
            }],
            height: 200,
            width: 400,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            listeners: {
                celldblclick: function(ctx, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex, e, eOpts) {
                    alert('You have clicked cell in the ' + cellIndex + ' column and ' + rowIndex + ' row')
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/dbl

Comment: Thnx...so here ctx means "context" ?

Comment: Yes, it is context (in current situation it is grid itself). You can use it as reference to your grid. Let's say for getting cell's value. Like that: ctx.store.getAt(rowIndex).get('name')

Comment: I did something like below and it worked perfectly

`listeners: { 
                    celldblclick: function(ctx, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex, e, eOpts) {
                        var grid = ctx.grid,                            
                            columnMgr = grid.getColumnManager(),
                            column = columnMgr.getHeaderAtIndex(cellIndex),
                            columnIndex = column.dataIndex;`